# Woocommerce - show checkbox at checkout for certain products and/or categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a custom checkbox during checkout that will only show for certain SKUs or Product categories. I already have this code that shows the checkbox on all checkout pages

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'bt_add_checkout_checkbox', 10 );
/**
 * Add WooCommerce additional Checkbox checkout field
 */
function bt_add_checkout_checkbox() {
   
    woocommerce_form_field( 'checkout_checkbox', array( // CSS ID
       'type'          => 'checkbox',
       'class'         => array('form-row mycheckbox'), // CSS Class
       'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
       'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
       'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
       'label'         => 'Custom label', // Label and Link
    ));    
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bt_add_checkout_checkbox_warning' );
/**
 * Alert if checkbox not checked
 */ 
function bt_add_checkout_checkbox_warning() {
    if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['checkout_checkbox'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge the Checkbox' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

I don't know much about PHP but I think I must use $cart_item and $product within a foreach loop and an if statement but I'm quite lost with this part, my logic says it would be something like this:

```
function bt_add_checkout_checkbox() {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $sku = WC()->cart->get_sku($product);
        if ($sku == 'SA300ARS'){
               
            woocommerce_form_field( 'checkout_checkbox', array( // CSS ID
               'type'          => 'checkbox',
               'class'         => array('form-row mycheckbox'), // CSS Class
               'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
               'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
               'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
               'label'         => 'I acknowledge that my product can take up to 24 hours to be delivered.  <a href="/checkout-checkbox" target="_blank" rel="noopener">(Unless the description says otherwise)</a>', // Label and Link
            )); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going in the right direction. You just need to modify the code like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', 'bt_add_checkout_checkbox', 10 );
/**
 * Add WooCommerce additional Checkbox checkout field
 */
function bt_add_checkout_checkbox() {
    //Check if wooCommerce is activated
    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
  
        //Define SKUs you want to check for
        $checkSKUs = ['sku1', 'sku2', 'sku3'];

        //Grab all the SKUs in cart
        $skus = array();
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            array_push($skus, $cart_item['data']->get_sku());
        }

        //Check if anything matches in both
        $matchingResult = array_intersect($checkSKUs,$skus);
        if (count($matchingResult) > 0) { 

            //If at least 1 SKU matches then generate checkout field
            woocommerce_form_field( 'checkout_checkbox', array( // CSS ID
                   'type'          => 'checkbox',
                   'class'         => array('form-row mycheckbox'), // CSS Class
                   'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
                   'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
                   'required'      => true, // Mandatory or Optional
                   'label'         => 'I acknowledge that my product can take up to 24 hours to be delivered.  <a href="/checkout-checkbox" target="_blank" rel="noopener">(Unless the description says otherwise)</a>', // Label and Link
            ));
        } 
    }   
}

   add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bt_add_checkout_checkbox_warning' );
    /**
     * Alert if checkbox not checked
     */ 
    function bt_add_checkout_checkbox_warning() {
        if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['checkout_checkbox'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge the Checkbox' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
```

I believe this should work. If not then let me know.
I've added comments for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now, I have just added some code so it works with product categories as well. I really appreciate your time. Cheers!

Comment: I actually ran into an issue. When the checkbox doesn't show up and if you try to pay, the warning that you must check the box pops up, even though the checkbox is not there. How could I fix this?

Comment: I managed to solve the issue from above, I just copied all the first part of 'bt_add_checkout_checkbox'.